# Check for a Null String in Java Apart from StringUtils

Tags: string, jakarta-ee, dreamweaver, null-check

Is there any gun shot method to find and check for a null string without getting into exceptions??

Please do not suggest StringUtils class please. I tried everything but i am a not able to compile that with the project.
I am using Tomcat and I am programming in the root folder of the tomcat and i have several jsp files which i am not able to link with StringUtils. I am programming using Dreamweaver.

Please Help,

Comment: You can open the source code of Apache StringUtils.isBlank or isNull and use the same code within your project.

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with the usual way?

```
if (str == null)
```

If by "null" you mean "blank" also, then

```
if (str == null || str.trim().isEmpty())
```

Comment: for blank you need to first trim the string i.e if(str == null) || str.trim().isEmpty());

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use like a function in jsp do following:

```
<%!
 // define a isNull() function
 static boolean isNull(String x){
    return (x == null || x.isEmpty());
 }
%>

then you can use above function anywhere inside JSP like 

<% if (isNull(xxx)){ %>
// html code
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much... I am loving this.... Doing this project for a temple.... So you all will get transcendental credit...